# How to handle .gql file imports in Jest tests

Tags: graphql, jestjs, apollo, vue-apollo, graphql-tag

I'm trying to test a component that imports a `.gql` file. When I try to build the component in a Jest file, I receive this error:

```
( object. anonymous function(module exports require __dirname __filename global jest) {
query getUser {                                                
      ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ
<script>
import GET_USER from 'PATH';
ˆ
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to ignore the import? Because I don't need to test the GraphQL call.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and replace the image with the actual error message? This will help other users find your question when they encounter the same error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GraphQL documents (which typically have a `.gql` extension) can be imported directly if you use webpack and utilize the loader that comes with `graphql-tag`. Jest does not work with webpack out of the box and needs to be configured to handle any imports of asset files like stylesheets, images, etc. This process is outlined [in the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack).

According to the `graphql-tag` documentation:

> Testing environments that don't support Webpack require additional configuration. For Jest use jest-transform-graphql.

So you can utilize [jest-transform-graphql](https://github.com/remind101/jest-transform-graphql) along with the `babel-jest` plugin, which you're probably already using:

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "\\.(gql|graphql)$": "jest-transform-graphql",
    ".*": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

Mocking the file is technically possible by adding the `moduleNameMapper` config option as shown in the docs, however, doing so is likely to break your components.

Comment: I had this issue on my `nuxt` project, the error disappeared after adding `jest-transform-graphql` as above and also adding `moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json', 'gql'],`.

Comment: `jest-transform-graphql` doesn't work with newer jest versions (>= v28). There is an issue tracking it and a workaround is explained [here](https://github.com/remind101/jest-transform-graphql/issues/13#issuecomment-1367564978).