# How to validate graphql schema with fragmented documents

Tags: node.js, graphql, jestjs

i was thinking it would be cool to support schema validation at the unit test level so we could be aware of breaking changes to queries when we upgrade our api

i’d like to set up the test so that it supports auto-discovery of any new `*.graphql` files  but in doing so, the jest process thinks the current working directory is in `__tests__`  so when i evaluate the graphql document manually with the loader, relative fragments in queries like this fail:

```
#import "./fragments/FullUserData.graphql"

query User(
  $zid: String!
) {
  user {
    userData: get(
      zid: $zid
    ) {
      ...FullUserData
    }
  }
}
```

failure message:

```
Error: Cannot find module './fragments/FullUserData.graphql' from 'schemaValidation-test.js'"
```

if i move fragments folder into  the `__tests__`  dir, the test gets happy.
any ideas on what I can do to trick the evaluation to process the fragment as if I was relative to the  fragment directory?

```
__tests__/
  - schemaValidation-test.js
queries/
  - someQuery.graphql
  - fragments/someFragment.graphql
```

i tried `process.chdir()` to the queries dir from within jest but no dice

here is the validator:

```js
// __tests__/schemaValidation-test.js
import glob from 'glob'
import { validate } from 'graphql/validation'
import loader from 'graphql-tag/loader'
import schema from 'api/lib/app/graphql/schema'
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

const gqlDir = path.join(__dirname, '..')

const queryDir = path.join(gqlDir, 'queries', 'shared')
const pattern = `${queryDir}/!(fragments)*.graphql`

const getGraphqlFiles = () => glob.sync(pattern)

describe('api schema', () => {
  const files = getGraphqlFiles()

  for(var file of files) {
    const buffer = fs.readFileSync(file)
    let document = (buffer || "").toString()

    try {
      document = eval(loader.call(
        { cacheable: () => ({}) },
        document
      ))
    } catch (e) {
      fail(`could not parse ${file}, ${e}`)
    }


    it(`${file} passes validation`, () => {
      const errors = validate(
        schema,
        document,
      )

      expect(errors).toEqual([])
    })
  }
})
```

How can I tell the loader I am in a different directory relative to the fragment?

Comment: FWIW, `graphql-tag` explicitly states it should not be used for testing. You should use `jest-transform-graphql` instead, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567937/how-to-handle-gql-file-imports-in-jest-tests/56568500#56568500).

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the above code will only validate your schema. If you're actually interested in identifying breaking changes, you should snapshot your schema and then use the [findBreakingChanges](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/findBreakingChanges.js) utility from the core library.

Comment: yes thats my immediate goal. i will check out the library you recommended. daniel, I am using the transformer as well. just not for this example, where i was wanting to support auto-discovery of *.graphql files added to repo

Comment: this library will not satisfy my needs, it looks as if it compares 2 schemas. I only have access to the single schema exposed by the API.

Comment: also, i am actively using graphql-tag in this case for fragment support. unless you are aware of another way to load graphql extensions and associated fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. The  key was to use `require` instead of `fs.readFileSync`

```js
import glob from 'glob'
import { validate } from 'graphql/validation'
import schema from 'api/lib/app/graphql/schema'
import path from 'path'

const gqlDir = path.join(__dirname, '..')
const queryDir = path.join(gqlDir, 'queries', 'shared')
const pattern = `${queryDir}/!(fragments)*.graphql`

const getGraphqlFiles = () => glob.sync(pattern)

describe('rent-js-api schema', () => {
  const files = getGraphqlFiles()
  files.forEach(file => {
    /* eslint-disable import/no-dynamic-require */
    const document = require(file)

    it(`${file} passes validation`, () => {
      const errors = validate(
        schema,
        document,
      )

      expect(errors).toEqual([])
    })
  })
})
```

here is jest.config.json

```
{
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/test/jest/shim.js",
    "<rootDir>/test/jest/setup.js"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "src", "test/jest", "test"],
  "collectCoverage": false,
  "testMatch": ["**/*-test.js"],
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "!**/src/**/*-test.js",
    "!**/index.{ts,js}",
    "!**/src/**/const.{ts,js}",
    "!**/ui/theme/**",
    "!**/src/**/*.d.{ts,tsx}",
    "!**/node_modules/**",
    "!**/src/ui/*/themes/**"
  ],
  "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/test/jest/noop-styles",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/test/jest/noop-binary",
    "^.+\\.html$": "<rootDir>/test/jest/htmlLoader"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "graphql",
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts",
    "tsx"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.graphql$": "jest-transform-graphql"
  },
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
    "^.*__tests__/__helpers__.*"
  ],
  "snapshotSerializers": [
    "enzyme-to-json/serializer",
    "jest-serializer-html"
  ]
}
```